# How to fix the error "cannot resolve method 'add(int, com.web"

Tags: java, android

I am getting an error

> cannot resolve method 'add
>   fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container,f1);

When I'm trying to run the application it is saying:

> unfortunately your application has stopped

Code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity{
    Button bn;
    boolean status = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        bn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bn);
        bn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                FragmentManager fragmentManager =getFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                if(!status)
                {
                     FragmentOne f1 = new FragmentOne();
                    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container,f1);
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
                    bn.setText("LOAD SECOND FRAGMENT");
                    status = true;
                }
                else
                {
                  FragmentTwo f2 = new  FragmentTwo();
                    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container,f2);
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
                    bn.setText("LOAD FIRST FRAGMENT");
                    status = false;

                }

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Your FragmentOne and FragmentTwo do not extend Fragment probably. Can you check what they extend?

Comment: Your FragmentOne and FragmentTwo do not extend with Fragment it might be extend with android.support.v4.app.Fragment check your import in fragment classes. You are using getFragmentManager() with Support fragments, u can use getSupportFragmentManager() to resolve this.

Comment: thank u Sir , but FragmentOne and Two extends Fragment ? i don t know what s piratically the problem?

Answer (score 2):

"MainActivity.java"  and  your fragment's java have to

use same 
import android.app.Fragment;   or
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

Answer (score 0):

## Update in 2022

I just got the same error and it looks like the old solution was working before but since Android is improving, there is a new update of typing that.

As a comparison, I think Google is trying to improve the efficiency and code performance by eliminating using the word **new** and using rather the support from the fragment manager in order to attach (commit) the fragment to the Activity directly!!

Ref: https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/create

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    boolean status = false;
    Button bn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        bn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bn);
        bn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (!status) {

                    status = true;
                    bn.setText("LOAD FIRST FRAGMENT");

                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                            .setReorderingAllowed(true)
                            .add(R.id.fragment_container, FragmentOne.class, null)
                            .commit();


                } else {

                    status = false;
                    bn.setText("LOAD SECOND FRAGMENT");

                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                            .setReorderingAllowed(true)
                            .add(R.id.fragment_container, FragmentTwo.class, null)
                            .commit();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```