# Android Studio 2.1 Linking Fragment

Tags: android

```
//Main activity.java

package com.example.sahilnitish.easyyagriculture;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
 boolean status=false;
    Button bn;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{    
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        bn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.bn);
        bn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
{
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                if(!status)
                {
                    Fragmentone f1 =new Fragmentone();
                    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container,f1);
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
                    bn.setText("Load Second fragment");
                    status=true;
                }
                else
                {
                    FragmentTwo f2 = new FragmentTwo();
                    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container,f2);
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
                    bn.setText("Load first fragment");
                    status=false;
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Error :-

> Error:(29, 40) error: no suitable method found for add(int,Fragmentone)
>   method FragmentTransaction.add(Fragment,String) is not applicable
>   (argument mismatch; int cannot be converted to Fragment)
>   method FragmentTransaction.add(int,Fragment) is not applicable
>   (argument mismatch; Fragmentone cannot be converted to Fragment)

fragmentone.java

```
package com.example.sahilnitish.easyyagriculture;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class Fragmentone extends Fragment 
{
    public Fragmentone() 
    // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one_layout, container, false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post your `Fragmentone`. This error message is telling you that `Fragmentone` does not extend the correct class.

Comment: When you post a question like this, you might want to point out which line the error is complaining about.

Comment: fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container,f1); this is the error line @GleenHowes

Comment: I have posted the fragmentOne @Tanis.7x

Comment: # Update in 2022 See this as is already answered there!
https://stackoverflow.com/a/70857951/12146581

Comment: # Update in 2022 See this as is already answered there!
https://stackoverflow.com/a/70857951/12146581

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the FragmentManager with a Support Fragment.

Either let your MainActivity extend ActivityCompat and use supportFragmentManager or let your Fragment extend a "normal" Fragment.

```
//Main activity.java
package com.example.sahilnitish.easyyagriculture;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{

    boolean status=false;
    Button bn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        bn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.bn);

        bn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                if(!status)
                {
                    Fragmentone f1 =new Fragmentone();

                    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container,f1);
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
                    bn.setText("Load Second fragment");
                    status=true;
                }
                else
                {
                    FragmentTwo f2 = new FragmentTwo();
                    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container,f2);

                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
                    bn.setText("Load first fragment");
                    status=false;
                }

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much that was really worked . @babadaba

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you're using wrong FragmentManager.

So, first change your import statement from :

```
import android.app.FragmentManager;
```

to :

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
```

and also you should use `getSupportFragmentManager()` in your case.

so change :

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
```

to :

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
```

Also your `Activity class` which is `MainActivity` in your case, should extend `AppCompatActivity` instead of `Activity`.

Comment: After making the changes still geting the error :- cannot resolve getSupportFragmentManager .

Comment: your `MainActivity` should extend `AppCompatActivity` instead of `Activity`. change that too and check if it works.

Comment: Look at my answer, your Activity needs to extend AppCompatActivity